# Readonly input box bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've got a strange bug, well, MSIE does.

Seems it is failing on all major MSIE versions: 6, 7, 8 and 9 (!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" ><head><title>test</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var test=jQuery('#in');
    test.focus(function(){
     if(test.val()=='empty')test.val('');
     test.attr('readonly',false);
    });
    test.blur(function(){
     if(test.val()=='')test.val('empty');
     test.attr('readonly',true);
    });
   });
  </script>

</head><body>

  <input type="text" value="empty" readonly="readonly" id="in"/>

</body></html>
```

Let me explain how this system works and what is going wrong.

When the user clicks (focuses) the input box, the input box should be made editable (ie, lose readonly flag). Then, when s/he leaves the input box (ie, blur event) some processing is done (not shown in code) and the input box is made readonly.

This works like a charm in most browsers (firefox, opera, webkit-based), but not any version of IE (including 9 beta).
The problem is that in IE, the user has to click the input box twice.

At this point, you might ask is the inputbox left readonly the first time?
No. I tested it, javascript reports that it is editable.

Easy fix, just fire a click event on the input box (to simulate the user's double click behavior), no?
No, `.click()` and `.focus()` both failed. No idea why.

**Edit:** Know that the cursor does show up in the text box, at least visibly.

**Important:** People, please do at least try the code before answering!

Comment: Why make it readonly at all, if a click makes it editable?

Comment: That's hardly a fix, or a constructive answer, at that.

Comment: That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @meager - What a sunny day it turned out to be! Don't you agree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a bug.
If you change the value, you also remove the current textRange.

Try `test.select()` , it should give the cursor back to the input.

```
test.focus()
```

will result in a loop that will end in an "not enough memory"-error.

Comment: Hi there! I'll try that out asap. However, I did use .focus() successfully, as in, I didn't get such an error. But as I said, it didn't work. Oh, this is important, know that the cursor is actually inside the input box, visibly, at least. (edited question)

Comment: `test.select()` fixed the problem thanks! but `test.focus()` did not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `readonly` should be `readOnly`. Seems weird you would toggle this property.  You can also try to remove it

```
jQuery("#foo").removeAttr("readOnly"); //.removeAttr("readonly");
```

Comment: uhm? It is "readonly" MSIE seems to change it to "readOnly", but it works just as well. Besides, that's past my issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this ive just tried that and it works:

```
<input type="text" value="empty" id="in" readonly/>
```