# readonly attribute in html not working consistantly with removeAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to disable to autofill prompt I get for the username and password field on my page and was quite successful in doing so after I introduced the below line in the existing code. `readonly onfocus="myFunc(this.id)`. Although I initially tried `autocomplete="false"` or `autocomplete="off"` wasn't of any help, I just let it be there.

```
<tr>                                                              
   <td align="right">Username:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="username" class="input" MAXLENGTH=8 size="25" autocomplete="false" id="username " readonly onfocus="myFunc(this.id)" onKeyPress="return submit(event)"></td>
</tr>
```

The point is the above code does help in disabling the autofill feature[in most of the browsers], but when I go and click on the empty text box to type username, the text box is empty and doesn't take any input from keyboard (as though it is still `readonly` - issue seen only in IE11).The color changes are applied when I click. The JS function called is as below.

```
function myFunc(x) {
  //x.removeAttribute('readonly'); 
  //x.style.background = "yellow";
  document.getElementById(x).removeAttribute("readonly"); 
  document.getElementById(x).style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Now a second click in the text box will let me type.Can somebody let me know how do I fix this behavior in IE.

Comment: It does work in chrome,firefox as well just like in the DEMO, but not in IE 11.

Comment: Just a suggestion that doesn't relate to your use of readonly attribute, but the root problem - I have also been frustrated in the past by browsers appearing to ignore `autocomplete="false"` - only to discover it must also be defined on the form that the element is a part of (eg. `<form method="POST" action="post.php" autocomplete="false"><input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="false"/></form>`). Recently, some browsers also have less respect for this attribute, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered here: [Readonly input box bug in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856266/readonly-input-box-bug-in-internet-explorer)

> Try `document.getElementById(x).select()` , it should give the cursor back to the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shashank Agrawal , this worked in my case.

Comment: i just happened to see, it does work well with IE11, but issue persist is older versions of IE.

Comment: For older versions of IE , use `readOnly` instead of `readonly` and it works !!